# Clang-format Error When Building Drake Python Bindings

Tags: drake

I am trying to install the Python bindings for Drake but am encountering an issue. I have followed the steps [here](https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html) from the "Binary Installation for Python" section up to "Building the Python Bindings". I am running the "make -j" step and am getting the following error:

```
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
make[2]: *** [drake_cxx_python-prefix/src/drake_cxx_python-stamp/drake_cxx_python-build] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The full traceback of the outputted error is:

```
ERROR: /Users/samcherna/Documents/6.832/drake/examples/rimless_wheel/BUILD.bazel:18:1: Action examples/rimless_wheel/gen/rimless_wheel_continuous_state.cc failed (Exit 1) lcm_vector_gen failed: error executing command bazel-out/host/bin/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen '--src=examples/rimless_wheel/rimless_wheel_continuous_state_named_vector.yaml' '--src=examples/rimless_wheel/rimless_wheel_params_named_vector.yaml' ... (remaining 5 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/samcherna/Documents/6.832/drake-build/_bazel_samcherna/816e2be05e81a09f0a948f564abb1d71/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/43/execroot/drake/bazel-out/host/bin/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen.runfiles/drake/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen.py", line 656, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/samcherna/Documents/6.832/drake-build/_bazel_samcherna/816e2be05e81a09f0a948f564abb1d71/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/43/execroot/drake/bazel-out/host/bin/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen.runfiles/drake/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen.py", line 652, in main
    return generate_all_code(args)
  File "/Users/samcherna/Documents/6.832/drake-build/_bazel_samcherna/816e2be05e81a09f0a948f564abb1d71/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/43/execroot/drake/bazel-out/host/bin/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen.runfiles/drake/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen.py", line 632, in generate_all_code
    generate_code(src, **kwargs_for_generate)
  File "/Users/samcherna/Documents/6.832/drake-build/_bazel_samcherna/816e2be05e81a09f0a948f564abb1d71/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/43/execroot/drake/bazel-out/host/bin/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen.runfiles/drake/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen.py", line 591, in generate_code
    [get_clang_format_path(), "--style=" + style, "-i"] + cxx_names)
  File "/Users/samcherna/Documents/6.832/drake-build/_bazel_samcherna/816e2be05e81a09f0a948f564abb1d71/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/43/execroot/drake/bazel-out/host/bin/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen.runfiles/drake/tools/lint/clang_format.py", line 15, in get_clang_format_path
    raise RuntimeError("Could not find required clang-format at " + path)
RuntimeError: Could not find required clang-format at /usr/local/opt/llvm@6/bin/clang-format
----------------
Note: The failure of target //tools/vector_gen:lcm_vector_gen (with exit code 1) may have been caused by the fact that it is running under Python 3 instead of Python 2. Examine the error to determine if that appears to be the problem. Since this target is built in the host configuration, the only way to change its version is to set --host_force_python=PY2, which affects the entire build.

If this error started occurring in Bazel 0.27 and later, it may be because the Python toolchain now enforces that targets analyzed as PY2 and PY3 run under a Python 2 and Python 3 interpreter, respectively. See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7899 for more information.
----------------
Target //:install failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /Users/samcherna/Documents/6.832/drake/BUILD.bazel:61:1 Action examples/rimless_wheel/gen/rimless_wheel_continuous_state.cc failed (Exit 1) lcm_vector_gen failed: error executing command bazel-out/host/bin/tools/vector_gen/lcm_vector_gen '--src=examples/rimless_wheel/rimless_wheel_continuous_state_named_vector.yaml' '--src=examples/rimless_wheel/rimless_wheel_params_named_vector.yaml' ... (remaining 5 argument(s) skipped)
```

Does anyone have any insight as to what might be causing the issue? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.  If you are doing the binary installation, then you do not need to run `make`.  I think you've gone past the "Binary Installation for Python" section, and wandered into the "Building the Python Bindings"?

If you made it to the end of the Binary Installation section, then you're in good shape!

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that they were separate options.